# Gnuplot: gif unknown terminal

Tags: gnuplot

I am using Gnuplot v5.0 patchlevel 4.

I tried to use the gif terminal to make a gif animation [see here](http://www.gnuplotting.org/animation-gif/). The problem is that I do not have the gif terminal among all the terminals. When I type `set terminal gif animate delay 100` I received the error message: `unknown or ambiguous terminal type`. Here the list of my terminals

```
Subtopics available for set terminal:
    cairolatex        canvas            cgm               context
    corel             dumb              dxf               eepic
    emf               emtex             epscairo          epslatex
    fig               hpgl              latex             mf
    mp                pcl5              pdfcairo          pngcairo
    pop               postscript        pslatex           pstex
    pstricks          push              qms               svg
    tek40xx           tek410x           texdraw           tgif
    tkcanvas          tpic              vttek             x11
    xlib              xterm
```

the `tgif` one is not working so, my question is, can I use/import in gnuplot a new terminal, such as the `gif` one ? Thanks

Comment: You cannot include terminals at later time, but you can use only those that were build into your gnuplot binary.

Comment: @Christoph thanks for the answer. This means I have to re-install, upgrade my gnuplot binary with one in which I have that particular terminal?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes.